# How can I find in openam repo from where the error message is getting invoked?

Tags: jsp, error-handling, single-sign-on, openam, forgerock

I am trying to find in the code from where the below error is getting called from forgerock openAM repo.

can anyone help in navigating in openAM to find the below error:

```
  "Plug-in org.forgerock.openam.idrepo.ldap.DJLDAPv3Repo encountered a ldap 
  exception. ldap errorcode=21"
```

Any help Appreciated!!

Comment: OpenAM can use both an internal or external repository. It can stores Data, Users and Tokens in the repo. Which version of AM are you using?

Comment: Also, where is this error throwed? Which file? What are you trying to do? Please be more specific and describe the use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, we need stack trace, but you can debug OpenAM source code here:
https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM/blob/master/openam-datastore/src/main/java/org/forgerock/openam/idrepo/ldap/DJLDAPv3Repo.java